# Figure out the height of object

Tags: three.js

If the distance between object and camera is 500, the view angle is 45, if I want the object just fills the whole screen, can I set one of the vertex in origin, and set 500 * Math.tan(45/2) to the y of another vertex. I have test it, it's incorrect, how can I figure out the y?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by myself. Math.tan only receive radians, so I should change it to this: 500 * Math.tan(45/2/180 * Math.PI)

Comment: Remember to mark this question as solved by accepting this answer (check mark on the left).